# Regex to return the description in hyperlink

Tags: .net, regex, hyperlink

Hi I'm using this code:

```
Dim expr As String = "\<(.|\n)+?\>"
```

and was trying to remove the hyperlink below:

```
<a href="https://support.sample.com/applications/ManagemyEngagements/Documents/SolutionContingency.html" target="_blank">demo </a>
```

My target is to return the hyperlink description "demo" but when trying to replace the matched items with an empty string all are being replaced.

Desired result:

```
demo
```

Please help

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

your string has 3 parts:
 A: `<a ...>`
 B: demo
 C: `</a>`

to match thous 3 parts you could use:
`/<a [^>]+>(.*?)<\/a>/`

`<a [^>]+>` match A, a string starting with ""
`(.*?)` match B, any data not greedy
`<\/a>` match C, a string ""

Comment: Do not forget the `s` modifier by adding `(?s)` to match newlines with `.` :)